# How do I create an icon shortcut in the linux - Centos navigation system?

Tags: centos

I downloaded a program called SmartCVS which came in a tar file which I extracted and stored into my home folder. To run the program, I use the terminal and enter my home folder and then into the program's folders -- (/home/username/smartcvs-7_1_9/bin) -- and run

```
[user@localhost]$ ./smartcvs.sh
```

to start the program. I however would like to add a shortcut here to run this program.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a “desktop” file in $HOME/.local/share/applications.  Look at the files that end with .desktop in /usr/share/applications/, and create your own file. Use Exec=/path/to/your/executable.

Once it’s there, it should appear with other applications when you go to the program launcher in GNOME, you can add from there.

Comment: I was successfully able to add my shortcut in the program launcher including an icon to go with it as well. However, there is no icon on the taskbar panel (bottom panel that displays current programs running) for my program. Is there another field I have to add besides the icon field to get the icon to show in the bottom panel as well?

Comment: Update. Nvm. Now the tab is showing Mozilla Thunderbird with the icon next to it but for several days it was not and I haven't made any changes to it. Weird.